# How can I restore an app on my iPad if it isn't available in the Store anymore?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I was using ios version 4 till yesterday, and I just upgraded the version. Some apps which I purchased before cannot be found in the app store or in the itunes purchases section.
what is to be done??

Answer (score 1):

If you had your iPad in sync with your computer, the app should still be in the "Apps" section of iTunes, available for you to synchronize with your restored iPad.

Alternatively, on your computer, select "iTunes Store", and from the "Quick Links" section on the upper-right hand side, select "Purchased", and then "Apps" (and then "iPad").  Some removed apps are still available for re-downloaded from that area.

Answer (score 1):

Apps fall into four categories:

- The version you had is still live on the App Store for purchase and re-download.
- The version you had is replaced by a newer version.
- The version you had is withdrawn from new sales, but available for re-download.
- The version is entirely removed from the store.

As written, it looks like the app you have in mind is in the last category. Your only hope there is to restore a backup copy from iTunes and sync that app over WiFi (if your iOS is new enough) or over USB cable.

As to the status of an app in my list above, the developer has total control over their desires to place, update or withdraw an app partially or totally. Of course Apple reviews these requests and can broker / take action above and beyond the developer.

If you fall into the last category where the app truly is not available, you have several options:

- Contact the developer and see if they can or will sell you the app through [Apple's B2B store](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/). That store operates under the same review, but both buyer and seller need to submit to extra steps other than making an Apple ID.
- Contact the developer and get a binary that you could then sign and distribute yourself as an [Apple iOS developer](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) or [Apple Enterprise Developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).
- Jailbreak your device and/or crack the code signing so that you can run a copy of that app (here you'll need a backup copy or a source of the app from someone else).